# Wrapping the content of itemscontrol with comboboxtext box in a row when window is minimized and to remain stretched when full screen

Tags: wpf

I have requirement where I need to show four combo box in a row which are added dynamically in an items control. Now I also need the behavior than when the window is re sized then the items in the items control would wrap not get small in size. I tried using wrap panel but the issue is that the items are not getting horizontally stretched although I have set horizontal alignment and content alignment to stretch.

How can I achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand you my friend but maybe this is something you are looking for:

http://wpftutorial.net/WrapPanel.html

Its called a WrapPanel and it....wraps its children into same column (under each other) once no enough space.